# Angular - Reactive Forms - How to pass an object to a FormGroup with a class and validators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a large form to create and decided to use the reactive form feature for ease of use. However, I am facing a few challenges that might be obvious and looking for help.

Below are two cases that yield the same outcome with the exception of the validation. The `createFormWithValidation()` method specifics every control and it's associated validators. The `createFromPassingObject()` method creates the same form using just the `this.party` object but without the added validators.

My goal is to pass an object to `this.fb.group()` that will have the controls that are part of the class and be able to specify validators for each property of the `Party` Class.

```
// The Class with the properties
export class Party {
  firstName: string = '';
  lastName: string = '';

  constructor() {}
}

// party Object
myForm: FormGroup;
this.party = new Party();

// Form with explicit controls and their validators

createFormWithValidation() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: [this.party.firstName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    lastName: [this.party.lastName, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
  })
}

// The goal is to achieve this type of method where this.party will be the object of the controls and their validators. 

createFormPassingObject() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group(this.party)
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I am doing for my case. Be aware that I am in the midst of working on my project as well so there's no guarantee that it will work and it will work properly. Anyway, this is how I do it:

```
// First is to define a const that is going to be the pre-defined object going in this.formBuilder.group()
export const predefinedFormGroup = {
 property1: new FormControl('', Validators go here),
 property2: new FormControl('', Validators go here)
}

// Create the form
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group(predefinedFormGroup);

// My use-case is I have to add new FormGroup to an existed FormGroup in an existed Form:
(<FormGroup>this.myForm.get['sections']).addControl(section.name, this.formBuilder.group(section.interface));
```

I hope I am making sense here.

Comment: OK, so what you are suggesting is to create another object that holds my data class in addition to the validators. Since the data class properties are essentially the  properties of the from group, I am thinking that there must be a way to do this in a generic fashion. Any ideas?

Comment: Essentially yes, you have to pass in an OBJECT. To my understanding, your `this.party` is not an OBJECT but an instance of the `Party` class. I guess if you want the VALUE of those class properties, you can do:
`this.myForm.addControl('name of control', this.formBuilder.control(this.party.firstName, Validators go here));`
But I'm thinking how you loop through an instance of a Class to get all the properties to create the proper controls for your `myForm`.

Comment: I just can't think of a way to make this generic because your validators will be specific per property in the data class. In which case I can't figure out how to create a function that take in the data class and a determine what validators belong to each class. It sounds like the best bet is to create each from group spelled out with all of the properties as oppose of relaying on `this.fb.group()` since the work to determine what the OBJECT (as you pointed out before) must be unique per implementation.

Comment: I'm looking for the same, I'd like to be able to create a FormGroup from a class that is the representation of the database table (model) so I'd write this.myForm = new FormGroup(class_instance); but I don't know if it's possible and how to do it.