# Angular reactive form based on model with validation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to create a reactive form basing on an existing data model with all the validation magic. In the example below author passes whole new object into a `formbuilder` but what I want to achieve is elegant way to tell `formbuilder` what field is required or needs some other validation.

https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-fundamentals-reactive-forms

```
export class PersonalData {
  email: string = '';
  mobile: string = '';
  country: string = '';
}
...
createFormGroupWithBuilderAndModel(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    return formBuilder.group({
      personalData: formBuilder.group(new PersonalData()),
      requestType: '',
      text: ''
    });
  }
```

I just want to skip the process of assigning a `FormControl` for each field in the model.

**@EDIT**

After some research and little hint from @xrobert35 I wanted to try and used https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators

Comment: I wish the form was just bindings directly to my model, and the constraints were just made as html-attributes. I have a rather complicated model, and it requires so much boiler-plate to go model-to-form and back form-to-model. For editing an existing model, I'm storing references back to the original entity. Not sure if there's a cleaner way. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They could be "many" way to do what you want to do,  but by just extending your actual solution : Your personnal data could look like :

```
export class PersonalData {
  email: string = ['', Validators.required];
  mobile: string = ['', Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)];
  country: string = '';
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but is it really elegant to mix up 'Validators' with data model classes?

Comment: Like I writed it, it's absolutly not elegant, And it would not put this class in my "model"  but it can be a "detached" elegant way to declare a Form. I didn't had time to search but I supposed that someone could already have made a "Decorator based model". With '@Email' '@Required' '@MaxLenght' etc :) that would be an elegant way

Answer (score 2):

If you need domain base validation (for reusable purpose) you can use [rxweb](https://docs.rxweb.io/getting-started) validations.

```
export class PersonalData {
    @required()
    email: string;

    @required()
    mobile: string;    

    @greaterThan({ fieldName: 'number2' })
    number1: number;
    
    @prop()
    number2: number;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    formGroup: FormGroup;
    constructor( private validation: RxFormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {      
        let person: PersonalData = new PersonalData();
        this.formGroup = this.validation.formGroup(person);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you just want to add validators to your field.

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

I can't be more precise to giving you the official documentation.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
    ]),
    'alterEgo': new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo),
    'power': new FormControl(this.hero.power, Validators.required)
  });

}
```

In this exemple the fields name and power are required and of course the syntaxe could differ but the flow is the same.

Does it helps you ?

**@EDIT**
There is the same post for your use case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47576916/7133262

Comment: No, I did not want to specify each FormControl but rather get them from passed class object.

Comment: Yes and correct me if Im wrong but I think this solution instigates me to put FormControls inside the model itself. I want to avoid that.