# How do I declare a model class using Typescript for Angular reactive Form

Tags: angular

I would like to create a model for reactive Form.

The JSON File look like this:

```
      {
        "ITEMS": [
          {
            "NAME": "aaa",
            "QUANTITY": ["140", "60"]
          }
        ]
      }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442815/angular-reactive-form-based-on-model-with-validation) could help you

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not about making the Form. It's about making the model i will use in a reactive Form :)

Answer (score 1):

Here have an example, `item.model.ts` and his application at `app.component.ts`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s3obqy?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

In your case with this stringified object you can parse like that at `app.component.ts` :

```
 yourString = ` {
        "ITEMS": [
          {
            "NAME": "aaa",
            "QUANTITY": ["140", "60"]
          }
        ]
      }`;

  foo: Item = JSON.parse(this.yourString);
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not what i want and it's not reflecting the JSON file :(

Comment: it should be something like this :

Comment: ```export class DataModel {
    const ITEMS: [string, string[]];
    const NAME: string;
    const QUANTITY: string[];

    constructor() {
    this.ITEMS[{this.NAME, this.QUANTITY[]}];
    }
}```

Comment: ITEMS is an array that containing a string call NAME and an array of string call QUANTITY :)

Comment: ```  yourString = ` {
        "ITEMS": [
          {
            "NAME": "aaa",
            "QUANTITY": ["140", "60"]
          }
        ]
      }`;

  foo: Item = JSON.parse(this.yourString); ```

Comment: Thanks Vitor, I found the answer and i gave it below on : "There is the model"

Answer (score 0):

There is the model:

```
export class DataModel {
    public ITEMS: any[];

    constructor(public NAME: string, public QUANTITY: Array<string>) {
        this.ITEMS = [{NAME, QUANTITY}];
    }
}
```